# Why does pairplot show as a variable when specified as hue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os

haberman = pd.read_csv('datasets_474_966_haberman.csv', names = ['age', 'op_year', 'axil_nodes', 'surv_status'])

# source of data = "https://www.kaggle.com/gilsousa/habermans-survival-data-set/kernels"

haberman.head()
```

```
   age  op_year  axil_nodes  surv_status
0   30       64           1            1
1   30       62           3            1
2   30       65           0            1
3   31       59           2            1
4   31       65           4            1
```

```
sns.set_style("whitegrid");
sns.pairplot(haberman, hue="surv_status", height=2);
plt.show()
```

[image]

Why does it show `surv_status` as another variable in pair plot when it has been specified as `'Hue'`?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is because pairplot assumes all float parameters to be variables. In this case, `surv_status` is coded as {1, 2}. To stop that, you need to specify the vars paramter in pair plot as in

```
sns.set_style("whitegrid");
sns.pairplot(haberman, hue="surv_status", height=2, vars=['age','op_year','axil_nodes']);
plt.show()
```

It will then produce the desired pair plot.

[image]